# Chinese Idiom puzzle 4

Tags: idioms, games

Please solve the following puzzle

[image]

1. The country is peaceful, citizens are happy. - 出自宋·吴自牧《梦梁录·山川神》
2. A talented man and a pretty lady (a good match) - 出自唐·李隐《潇湘录·呼延冀》。
3. Heros show themselves when the world is in chaos
4. Have great literary talent - 出自南朝·宋·无名氏《释常谈·斗之才》
5. Do not judge someone's worthiness by his success or failure 出自《庄子*盗跖》
6. Confucius' philosophy on education - 語出《論語.衛靈公第十五》
7. Smart people think alike - 語本《三國志·蜀書·龐統傳》裴松之注引《江表傳》
8. Unsung Hero
9. The meaning of 武《左傳·宣公十二年》
10. A truly wise man would seem like a fool in common people's eyes - 出自《贺欧阳少师致仕启》
11. Great grace - 語出. 明·冯梦龙《醒世恒言》第十七卷
12. Near the end of time - 出自唐·李贺《致酒行》
13. Step into a trap 語出. 《三俠五義．第五五回》
14. wish someone to get unexpected wealth - 常見暉春字句
15. There's always a higher mountain  - 民间俗语
16. Upstand gentleman 出自《舊唐書·崔胤傳》
17. Know the law and still break the law - 出自清·吴敬梓《儒林外史》
18. Of indomitable　spirit 出自:宋·釋普濟《五燈會元·道場無庵法全禪師

A. A man of both civil and military ability 出自《舊五代史·和凝傳》

B. No one would pick up and keep someone else's lost item 《韓非子·外儲說左上》

C. A huge army can do 《晉書．卷一一四．苻堅載記下》

D. A match made in heaven; Congratulations on a happy marriage

E. A mind like still water - 出自《祭李侍郎文》

F. Lament the difficulties of the times, pity people's pain - 出自《争臣论》

G. Although the net of heaven is wide and sparse, it will never let bad guys get away - 語出《老子．第七三章》

H. Although people have talents, they have no chance to use them. 《資治通鑑．卷六五．漢紀五十七．獻帝建安十三年》

I. To save people by practicing medicine

J. The true color of a hero - 出自.明方汝浩《禅真逸史》第三十四回

K. Know heroes, respect hero

L. Summary execution - 見 .清·吴趼人《二十年目睹之怪现状》第六十五回

M. Fully reveal your ability

N. Everyone has their own opinions on the same thing

O. Outstanding talent and strategy - 出自. 唐．王勃〈三國論〉

P. A foolish old man wanted to move the mountain (it is a metaphor of unremitting efforts, not afraid of hardships, and self-achieving) 見《列子．湯問》

Q. Taishan Mountain and the Big Dipper (It is a metaphor for people who have high morals, high reputation, or outstanding achievements and are admired by everyone) - 出自. 《新唐書·韓愈傳贊》

R. Pillar that supports the sky - 見《唐大詔令集．卷六四．大臣．鐵券．賜陳敬瑄鐵券文》

S. Describe a grace that is heavy like a mountain - 出自. 宋·陆游《删定官供职谢启》

T. Unmatched in the world - 見. 英烈傳˙第七十回

More Hints below:

> [image]

Comment: Hod did you make the second picture only appear when mouse is hovering over it?

Comment: @zyy  begin with  >!  add  a  space and then place the picture

Comment: This sort of puzzles (the ones with hints) are a good field to apply Bayesian ideas. That is, there are some idioms that are almost sure to be that, like XX八斗，from which you get 雄XX略。Or 天XX恢 —— 自XX网 —— X鞭XX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are: (in both simplified and traditional)

> 1. 国泰民安 國泰民安  
>  2. 才子佳人 才子佳人 
>  3. 乱世出英雄 亂世出英雄 
>  4. 才高八斗 才高八斗 
>  5. 不以成败论英雄 不以成敗論英雄 
>  6. 有教无类 有教無類 
>  7. 英雄所见略同 英雄所見略同 
>  8. 无名英雄 無名英雄 
>  9. 止戈为武 止戈為武
>  10. 大智若愚 大智若愚
>  11. 大恩大德 大恩大德
>  12. 天荒地老 天荒地老
>  13. 自投罗网 自投羅網
>  14. 横财就手 横财就手
>  15. 一山更比一山高 一山更比一山高
>  16. 正人君子 正人君子
>  17. 知法犯法 知法犯法
>  18. 顶天立地 頂天立地
>  A. 文武全才 文武全才
>  B. 路不拾遗 路不拾遺
>  C. 投鞭断流 投鞭斷流
>  D. 佳偶天成 佳偶天成
>  E. 心如止水 心如止水
>  F. 悲天悯人 悲天憫人
>  G. 天网恢恢疏而不漏 天網恢恢疏而不漏
>  H. 英雄无用武之地 英雄無用武之地
>  I. 悬壶济世 懸壺濟世
>  J. 英雄本色 英雄本色
>  K. 识英雄重英雄 識英雄重英雄
>  L. 就地正法 就地正法
>  M. 大展身手 大展身手
>  N. 见仁见智 見仁見智
>  O. 雄才大略 雄才大略
>  P. 愚公移山 愚公移山
>  Q. 泰山北斗 泰山北斗
>  R. 一柱擎天 一柱擎天
>  S. 恩重如山 恩重如山
>  T. 举世无双 舉世無雙

As a secondary hint, there are a lot of

> 英雄

Comment: Really wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

> [image]

> Scharlach Nachtfalter's answer has (M) 大展身手 instead of [大顯身手](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E5%A4%A7%E9%A1%AF%E8%BA%AB%E6%89%8B); (15) 一山更比一山高 instead of [一山還有一山高](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E5%B1%B1%E9%82%84%E6%9C%89%E4%B8%80%E5%B1%B1%E9%AB%98). I would accept the variants as a correct answer